# Wordpress comment_form() issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to 'validate' a WP Theme using the Theme Checker plugin, the problem is that I get the following error:

REQUIRED: Could not find comment_form. See: comment_form
`<?php comment_form(); ?>`

I am using `<?php comments_template(); ?>` to generate the form, so if I include the `<?php comment_form(); ?>` it will duplicate the whole inputs for comment form.

[This](https://github.com/milohuang/reverie/blob/master/comments.php) is my comments.php

Comment: I guess the error is quite self-explanatory: your code doesn't contain a call to comment_form(). Also, I can't see any calls to comments_template(). Are you sure that it gets called?